# What do I need to install to make code contracts work with vs 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, code-contracts

I have vs 2008 and vs 2010 installed on my machine as well as the code contract from devlabs (version  1.2.21023.14). It works fine with vs 2008. However, with vs 2010, there is no "code contract" tab. Is there something I should install?

Comment: You'll need to document which version of Code Contracts you've installed.

Comment: No, this should be working fine. Are you using the 'VSTS' version, and what version of VS2010 are you running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you installed VS2010 last. You probably need to re-run the [code contracts installer from devlabs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992.aspx) to make the code contracts tab appear in VS2010.